# how to use promise in a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vue-component, json-ld

This is the parent Vue below:

```
<template>
<div id="app" class="">
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="content">
   <div class="container-fluid"> 
      <b-container>
        <router-view
          :srcUrl="srcUrl" :responses="responses[activityIndex]"
          v-on:updateProgress="updateProgress"
          v-on:saveResponse="saveResponse"
        />
      </b-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import jsonld from 'jsonld/dist/jsonld.min';
export default {
name: 'App',
data() {
 return {
  schema: {},
  activityIndex: null,
  responses: {},
};
},
watch: {
$route() {
  if (this.$route.params.id) {
    this.activityIndex = this.$route.params.id;
  }
},
},
mounted() {
axios.get(config.githubSrc).then((resp) => {
  this.schema = resp.data;
  this.progress = _.map(this.schema.ui.order, () => 0);
  this.responses = _.map(this.schema.ui.order, () => new Object());
  if (this.$route.params.id) {
    this.activityIndex = this.$route.params.id;
  }
});
},
computed: {
  srcUrl() {
    if (this.activityIndex) {
      jsonld.expand(this.schema, result => {
        return result;
      });
    }
    return null;
  },
}
};
</script>
```

How do I use jsonld.expand in vue computed method srcUrl to get it to return something in child vue? jsonld is an async function as far as i think. Hence it doesnt work when I write it this way. all i get in the child is a pending Promise.

How can I solve this?

the child vue has this:

```
props: ['srcUrl', 'responses'],
watch: {
srcUrl() {
  if (this.srcUrl) {
    this.getData();
  }
},
},
mounted() {
if (this.srcUrl) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  console.log('Home mounted: ', this.srcUrl);
  this.getData();
}
},
};
</script>
```

Comment: could you put more details?

Comment: jsonld.expand is an async function i think. because when i call the srcUrl in the child vue, it returns Promise pending. so ideally, i would like to use return the result from this async method (jsonld.expand) from the srcUrl method

Comment: yes it's promise, so please paste the whole code or the relevant part in order to help you

Comment: I've edited the question with the code added

Comment: I edited on the link you had sent. cannot find that comment of yours here now.